# Define AKS pod-cidr from UI

Tags: azure, azure-aks

Is there a way to define pod-cidr from ui on azure AKS?
From cli there is something like

```
--pod-cidr
```

But I cannot find anything similar on the graphical interface.

Answer (score 2):

Fairly certain that is not possible with the portal. because you cant configure anything with the basic settings and with advanced its using azure networking, not kubenet.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#kubenet-basic-networking
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-network#azure-cni-advanced-networking

Comment: Like I said I can do that by cli. It seems to me a little weird to connect pods by default with the nodes subnet. Why it is the default?

Comment: read on advanced networking in AKS. with advanced networking its using azure cni which allocates ip addresses in the subnet to the pods. that does not happen with kubenet. you can configure kubenet to some extent using ARM templates or rest api. CLI might not support that, but with azure cni pods will always have ip addresses from the subnet. you can use NSG to limit comms or network policies in kubernetes.